# Showing all details when there is more than just the specified parameter within the details

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

The title might be a bit long/confusing and possibly misleading so let me set up the scenario.

```
Columns - {Table.FruitDesc} {Table.FruitColor} {Table.FruitQty}

GH1a    | Basket 1                  |
GH1b    | Fruit      | Color  | Qty |
GH1c    |------------|--------|-----|
Details | Strawberry | Red    |  3  |
  ...   | Apple      | Green  |  1  |
  ...   | Banana     | Yellow |  9  |

<new set>

GH1a    | Basket 2                  |
GH1b    | Fruit      | Color  | Qty |
GH1c    |------------|--------|-----|
Details | Kiwi       | Green  |  1  |
  ...   | Grape      | Purple |  7  |
  ...   | Plum       | Red    |  2  |

<new set>

GH1a    | Basket 3                  |
GH1b    | Fruit      | Color  | Qty |
GH1c    |------------|--------|-----|
Details | Apple      | Green  |  8  |
  ...   | Kiwi       | Green  |  5  |
```

Now let's say I have a parameter `{?Fruit}` that I use to show a list of all the possible fruit.

I would like to pass that parameter to the report and have it return ALL the fruit in a basket that contains the specified fruit.

Something like: `{?Fruit} IN {Table.FruitDesc}` - which would not work.

If I were to pick `Apple` for `{?Fruit}` I want it to return all of the results of `Basket 1` and `Basket 3` not just `Basket 1` and `Basket 3` showing only the `Apple` line in the details as this would throw off a running total of the basket size.

In other words - I'm looking for all baskets containing `Apple` and their ACTUAL size with associated contents.

Hope I explained myself well.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is `simple` but implementation is a **tedious task**

My approach would be:

1. Don't use `{?Fruit} IN {Table.FruitDesc}` in record sort expert as this will produce wrong result as per your requirement...
2. For your requirement you need to store all values of the `Fruit` in a array as shown below. Creata a formula `@Add`

   ```
   Shared StringVar Array x;

   x:=x+Fruit;
   1
   ```

   Place above formula to the extreme right in the detail section... and supress it.
3. Now in go to the section expert of `GH1a`, `GH1b`, `GH1c` and `Details` and write a supress formula so that when `{?Fruit}` is in the array then `dont supress` and if not exists the `supress`.

   ```
   EvaluateAfter{@Add};
   Local NumberVar i;
   Local BooleanVar a;
   Shared StringVar Array x;
   for i:=0 to count(x) do
   (
   if x[i]={?Fruit}
   then 
   a:=true
   else 
   a:=false
   );

   if (a=true)
   then false    //if true then don't supress.. here true means value in array
   else true     //if true then supress.. here false means value is not in array
   ```

Above formula will supress if `{?Fruit}` not exits in list else will display

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a formula (a regular formula and not a record selection formula) like:

```
// {@MatchFruit} formula
if {?Fruit} in {Table.FruitDesc} then 1 else 0
```

Then all you need to do is suppress your group if the sum of this formula is equal to 0. In other words, suppress the group if no fruit in the basket matches the parameter:

```
// Suppression formula for your Basket group
if sum({@MatchFruit},{Table.BasketID})=0
```